# SSH session often freezes

Tags: ssh

I've been using my raspberry pi over SSH for quite some time now, and still one of the most annoying things that I couldn't fix is that everytime a certain amount of text is displayed, the connection will freeze and I have to disconnect myself.

Most of the time I use putty, because I work a lot with my windows PC, but the problem also happens with a default session with linux mint, so I guess it's the raspberry's problem.

First of all the problem is seemingly random, sometimes it happens when I call `apt-get update` or I paste some commands, very often when using nano, but it happens 100% of the time when the shell is filled with programs that use a "GUI shell", most notably the connection freezes everytime I try to open `raspi-config`.

I have a relatively slow connection with the raspberry, but it is able to handle a VNC connection so it should definetely be fast enough.

Comment: Which type of RPI? And how are you connected to the internet? If it's with wifi via USB this might be helpful: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/31260/37956

Comment: I have a raspberry pi3, connected through integrated WiFi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, 2 years late, but I've find out that the problem was just the wi-fi connection. It was not only very slow, but it also lost an appreciable amount of packets (from 20% to 30%), so it was enough to use the ethernet connection instead.